# How to clear a Text Box in angularJS, when click any link in the page AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I've a search box and multiple categories links available in the HTML page.

as soon as user input in searchBox, i want to show:

```
p in Products | filter {serachedText}
```

When user clicks a category hyperlink, i want to show

```
p in Products | filter {categoryID}
```

But because serachedText is still avialble, result showing for

```
p in Products | filter {categoryID} | filter {serachedText}
```

Is there any way i can clear the serachedText as soon as user clicks on anylink.

Comment: When a user clicks on the link, set the variable that is bound as the ngModel of the search box as an empty string ('').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter expression is wrong.

if your data is a JSON array having category and name properties like so:

```
self.Products = [
  { category: 1, name: 'Pencil' },
  { category: 1, name: 'Notebook' },
  { category: 2, name: 'Kitten' }
];
```

And you are binding the following things for the selected category and search text:

```
self.category = 1;
self.searchText = 'pen';
```

You could create a complex filter expression like so:

```
filter: { category: vm.category | name: vm.searchText }
```

This will filter both on category and searchText or in combination.

To clear out the searchText, you can watch if category changes using $scope.$watch and when it changes, clear up the searchText.

Take a look at the example below or at http://plnkr.co/edit/OEDvOn.  In the example, my filter expression is a bit more complicated since the selected category is actually an object containing value and name properties for the selected category, thus I need to add .value to get the right thing to pass to the filter.

Another point: For doing client side filtering, this is fine, but if you are filtering on server side, I'd rather get the filtering done on a service layer and just returned the filtered result instead of all possible data... save bandwidth and transfer time.

```js
(function(undefined) {
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp',[]);
  
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('searchCtrl', searchCtrl);
    
  searchCtrl.$inject = ['$log', '$scope'];
  
  function searchCtrl($log, $scope) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var self = this;
    
    self.searchText = undefined;
    
    self.categories = [
      { value: undefined, name: 'All' },
      { value: 1, name: 'Fruit' },  
      { value: 2, name: 'Snacks' },
      { value: 3, name: 'Flower' },
      { value: 4, name: 'Pet' },
      { value: 5, name: 'Stationary' }
    ];

    self.category = self.categories[0];
    
    self.data  = [
      { category: 1, name: 'Apple' },
      { category: 1, name: 'Grapes' },
      { category: 2, name: 'Dorito' },
      { category: 2, name: 'KitKat' },
      { category: 3, name: 'Roses' },
      { category: 3, name: 'Orchid' },
      { category: 4, name: 'Hamster' },
      { category: 4, name: 'Kitten' },
      { category: 5, name: 'Pencil' },
      { category: 5, name: 'Notebook' }
      ];
    
    $scope.$watch(function() { return self.category; }, function(val, old) {
      self.searchText = undefined;
    });
  }

}());
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="searchCtrl as vm">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="cat.name for cat in vm.categories" ng-model="vm.category">
        </select>
      </div>
    
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="textbox" ng-model="vm.searchText" placeholder="Search text here..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
        </span>
      </div>
      
      <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-top:20px">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in vm.data | filter:{category:vm.category.value, name:vm.searchText}">
          <li>{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be really easy to do in angularjs.

In html.

```
<input ng-model="mytext">
<a href ng-click="mytext=''">Clear Text</a>
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/sk1bqmmL/)

Comment: Even if we have many text boxes, we can use the same solution. [jsfiddle is here for multiple text version.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/sk1bqmmL/2/)

Comment: Nope, what we do if I have lot of texbox but i have only one button. :(

Comment: The point of this example is to set the value of scope somehow. [jsfiddle is here for multiple text box and one clear button.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/sk1bqmmL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest directive will be the best option

**MarkUp**

```
<input ng-model="mytext">
<a href ng-click="mytext=''" clear="mytext">Clear Text</a>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            clear: '='
        },
        compile: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
            ele.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.clear = undefined;
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```